# tsoutliers and use replacements

Tags: r, time-series, outliers

I used tsoutliers() to identify the outliers in my outcome measure and it made some suggestions for replacement values to use; however, I am unsure how to replace the values in the data.

I would like to create a variable to flag the records which are outliers or not (1 and 0) using the information from the $index part of the output; I tried the following but with no luck:

```
tsoutliers(df$Y)
df$outliers = which(is.na(tsoutliers(df$Y)$index), 1, 0)
```

I would also like to replace the observed values with the ones from the $replacements output.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you're referring to the `tsoutliers()` function from the `forecast` package.

Here are two ways to do it. The first uses the `tsoutliers()` function and manually replaces the identified outliers. The second uses the automated `tsclean()` function which both finds outliers and replaces them.

```
library(forecast)

# Create data set with one outlier
df <- data.frame(Y = rnorm(200))
df$Y[50] <- 10

# Find outlier and suggested replacement
tsoutliers(df$Y)

# Replacement method 1 
out <- tsoutliers(df$Y)
df$Y[out$index] <- out$replacements

# Replacement method 2
df$Y <- tsclean(df$Y)
```

Comment: Thank you. When I use replacement method 1, I get the following error message for:

```
df$Y[out$index] <- out$replacements
```
"Error in out$replacements : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

Comment: That suggests you are not using the tsoutliers function from the forecast package.

Comment: Method 2 works but unfortunately I can't get method 1 to work on my data even after changing the code so to read:

```
out <- forecast::tsoutliers(df$Y)
df$Y[out$index] <- out$replacements
```